# How to supply password to sudo su in script

Tags: scripts

Example script:

```
sudo su admin
ls /usr/bin
exit
```

When I run it with:

```
biske@comp1:~$ ./script
```

Then prompt is changed to:

```
admin@comp1:/home/biske$
```

When I type exit it actually prints those lines:

```
exit bin  games  include  lib  lib32  local sbin  share  src
```

I wanted output without requiring user to enter anything.

I suppose problem could be solved by feeding this `sudo su` commmand with password.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo su user` will fork into a new shell. That's the last thing you want to do when in a non-interactive script. Sorry, I mean that's the last thing you want to do in a script ***after*** hard-coding a password into it! Please avoid that.

You would be much better off skipping `su` and using sudo on its own:

```
sudo -u admin -- ls /usr/bin
```

Or failing that, just making sure your script is run as root with this block:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

And then there's no need for interacting inside the script at all. Your script can `sudo -u... command` anything without needing to change password.